# Postgresql with Postgis Geodjango Installation

Tags: django, postgresql, installation, postgis, geodjango

I'm trying to get Geodjango set up with Postgis but cannot enable the Postgis extension in the database. I am following the settings that are found on the [Geodjango Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/postgis/), but when I hit this step:

```
mydb=# CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.1/share/postgresql/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
```

Is this a problem with my paths? If so, how do I fix it? I found that my postgresql is located here:

```
admins-macbook:postgis-2.1.0 Admin$ find . -iname postgresql
./java/jdbc/src/org/postgresql
./java/jdbc/stubs/org/postgresql
```

Thanks for any ideas that will help!

Answer (score 1):

First I'd check if the files exists at all on your system with: find /usr -name postgis.control

Chances are it doesn't exist...

I believe this is a problem with the way 9.3.1 is packaged.

Look in /usr/pgsql-9.3/share/contrib/postgis-2.1 (change this path according to your postgis version)

If you see files in here like postgis.sql and spatial_ref_sys.sql then you can manually create a spatial database template using the instructions here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/postgis/#creating-a-spatial-database-template-for-earlier-versions

You will just have to change POSTGIS_SQL_PATH to point to the .sql files mentioned above.